# Refactoring asynchronous JS pre-rendering code

Tags: javascript, mvc, asynchronous, promise

A few months ago I wrote this module but, coming back to it, I find it a bit hard to read and reason about. I want to ask community's opinion on whether this needs to be refactored, and how I could approach this.

```
(function (q) {

  'use strict';

  var DELAY_BEFORE_RENDERING_NEXT_PAGE_VIEW = 3 * 1000;

  window.st.viewer.Helper.PageViewFactory = (function () {
    function promiseRenderView(page, token) {
      return page.fetchUnlessReady()
        .then(token.throwIfCanceled)
        .then(function () {
          var view = new window.st.viewer.View.PageView({
            model: page
          });

          view.render();
          return view;
        });
    }

    var scheduledPage,
        scheduledPromise;

    function scheduleRenderNextView(page, token) {

      // After some time passes, prefetch and prerender next page view
      // so if it is requested (very likely), we can re-use an existing promise.

      scheduledPage = null;
      scheduledPromise = null;

      q.delay(DELAY_BEFORE_RENDERING_NEXT_PAGE_VIEW)
        .then(token.throwIfCanceled)
        .then(function () {
          return page.promiseNext();
        })
        .then(token.throwIfCanceled)
        .then(function (nextPage) {
          if (nextPage) {
            scheduledPage = nextPage;
            scheduledPromise = promiseRenderView(nextPage, window.st.Helper.CancellationToken.getNone());
          } else {
            scheduledPage = null;
            scheduledPromise = null;
          }
        })
        .catch(token.catchItself)
        .done();
    }

    function scheduleRenderView(page, token) {
      var promise = (page !== scheduledPage) ?
        promiseRenderView(page, token) :
        scheduledPromise;

      scheduleRenderNextView(page, token);

      return promise;
    }

    return {
      scheduleRenderView: scheduleRenderView
    };
  })();
})(Q);
```

This module exports a single function called `scheduleRenderView`. Its purpose is, given a `page` model and a cancellation token, do the following steps asynchronously:

1. Fully fetch `page` model (it may be loaded partially);
2. Create and render (in memory) a `PageView` for it;
3. Return this view to the caller;
4. Additionally, after a 3 second delay:

   - Request next `page` by calling `promiseNext`;
   - Pre-render next page by repeating steps 1-3 for it and store the pre-rendered view **in case it gets requested the next time** `scheduleRenderView` is called (very likely)

The user views pages one by one, and I wanted to anticipate the most likely scenario where she will request the next page.

I also wanted to make this optimization invisible to the calling code.

Is this code hard to comprehend? Are the simpler ways to achieve the same?

Comment: I must say, this sure looks like a complicated way to express what it is you're trying to do.  If it were me, I'd back up to first principles and find a much easier way to express what I was trying to do.  I don't understand enough about what you're trying to do to take a crack at it.

Comment: @jfriend00: What is it that you don't understand? I'll happily clarify this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this code hard to comprehend? Yes.

That is because there are a lot of unknown functions: `view.render`, `page.fetchUnlessReady`, `token.catchItself` ,`token.throwIfCanceled` or `window.st.Helper.CancellationToken.getNone()` etc. etc.

In my mind, I would approach this more like :

```
function scheduleRenderView( page )
{
  //Load and display the page
  var promise = model.loadPage( page ).then( function(){
    view.renderPage( model.getPage( page ) );
  });
  //Load the next page
  model.loadPage( page.next() );
  return promise;
}
```

`loadPage` would either return immediately if we retrieved already the data once ( from cache ) or download the page model.

`getPage` gets a page model from cache

`renderPage` would do the obvious

This means I would forego the pre-rendering which really sounds like pre-mature optimization, how long could that take?

2 other minor comments:

- Why access some variables through `window`, that does not seem to make sense
- In my mind, adding functions to the `window.st.viewer.Helper` is terrible global variable abuse, not to mention that you probably should add it to `Helper.prototype`.

Comment: Pre-rendering is not an immature optimization, there was a real need for it. What do you suggest for namespacing instead of `window.st.viewer.*`? `Helper` is a namespace, not a class, why add something to its prototype? Again, `window.st` is just a root namespace.

Comment: Do you think I should re-word the question to remove any methods specific to my code (`fetchUnlessReady`, etc, and only leave the “essence” of the code)?

Comment: To make it clear: `CancellationToken` is a class, `getNone` is its static method. It's not just some global variable.

Comment: Your suggestion might make it easier indeed to review.

Comment: Also, you could just use `st` for your namespace, there is no need for using `window`, I am sure you can avoid local variable clashes.

Comment: In fact you were right. Rendering *was* a premature optimization. It renders view in DOM and begins to fetch images, fonts, etc, so it *looks* like a useful optimization. What I didn't realize, is that I'm scheduling it too early—before the *current* view's resources probably have loaded, so it *slowed down current view's rendering*. I cut this code completely, fixed a couple of problems, and seems to run more smoothly now. So you were right after all!

Answer (score 1):

Two more points to complement [konijn's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/38806/2634) to my question:

- I'm moving from `window.st.*` madness to using [require.js](http://requirejs.org) with [Almond](https://github.com/jrburke/almond) (I wish I did this before);
- Instead of hand-rolled cancellation mechanism, I'm moving from Q to [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) which already [supports opt-in cancellation](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#cancellation).